# mysql calculation query take long time ???

Tags: mysql, optimization

select id,date_time,**(round((A/12000)*336.00*0.1592,2))** as adata,**(round((B/12000)*619.20*0.1597,2))** as bdata from table

This type of query take long time to respond data how to optimize time or reduce time in this type of query

Answer (score 0):

That query reads all the rows from `table`.  That is the slowest part of the operation.

The `ROUND` function and arithmetic take a relatively insignificant amount of the total time.

Another thing that *may* be involved is interference with `table` from other queries.

To discuss this further, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table`;
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "table";
some timings
and any further evidence
```